How are photons related to the electromagnetic field and in turn how are they related to the normal forces we see today?
I have been looking for a while and I still don’t completely understand the electromagnetic force and its relations to photons or the normal forces for example the force that counteracts gravity, keeping the book in the table. Some places say the the charges on the table repel the book keeping it from falling down due to gravity although how is this related to the photons, what part would they, along with the electromagnetic force, play in this as the charges already repel.
Additionally could someone explain what are virtual photons. Some places I hear that virtual photons carry the electromagnetic force and in other places just photons. Apparently they are the same particles but one is detectable?

You really should ask one question per post, but I will try to answer all.

There are two reasons why a book does not pass through the table, of said in another way, there are two reasons why we exist and don't collapse into a black hole: 1) The electromagnetic force between molecules of various materials prevent them from passing through each other. 2) the exchange interaction (that is to say, the Pauli exclusion principle) prevents the fermions (for example the electrons) from being in the same state. So two electrons with the same quantum numbers cannot be at the same position simultaneously.

Virtual photons are internal lines of Feynman diagrams representing amplitude matrix elements, by loop order. This is a technical name for saying that they are mathematical artifacts of the perturbative expansion of the amplitude matrix we use in Quantum Field Theory. Feynman diagrams are just that: diagrams. They do not represent what is happening in real life, and I would say even more strictly that they only represent what is happening in the momentum space. In real space, you have to integrate all the momenta a virtual particle can have and it turns out that you can deduce the Coulomb law from assuming stationary test charges. The Coulomb potential is given by the expectation value of a Wilson loop representing two stationary test charges describing a rectangle $\square$. More precisely, we have:
\begin{equation}
\langle W_\square[A] \rangle \sim e^{-V_\text{Coulomb}(r)T}
\end{equation}
See Srednicki eq(82.22). Here, $T$ is the time interval of the interaction, $A$ is the gauge field (the potential of the Electromagnetic field), and $V$ coulomb is the Coulomb potential energy.


Real photons on the other side are perturbations of the electromagnetic field due to the presence of charges, that are observable are crucial in the calculations of QED, because of the Kinoshita-Lee-Nauenberg theorem asserting that infrared divergencies are perfectly balanced out by the emission of soft, real, photons, the processes we are considering in the calculations.
I don't have too much time but let me know in the comments if I should expand some parts so that ist is clearer.

Thanks, that does really help. Although could I quickly ask, are the photons that carry the electromagnetic force the same as the ones which are the particles of light

Also, is it the electromagnetic magnetic force the force that causes friction, air resistance, magnetism or some of the other common forces you learn in physics @Jeanbaptiste

@NicoSkopek In QFT, you need to think in terms of fields rather than particles. In my Wilson loop expectation value, the variable is the gauge field $A$. This is the field unifying the scalar potential and the vector potential of the Maxwell equations. Ultimately, the electromagnetic force causes friction and air resistance. Magnetism is a consequence of particles of matter having a charge and a spin (with some subtleties), but yes, without the electromagnetic field, no electric and magnetic fields.
